# Invalid type of arguments C

Tags: c, arrays, file

I am trying to implement a function that read lines from a file and put them into a string array. But it gives me the warning:

> expected char ** But argument is of type char * (*)[(sizetype)(numberOfchar)]

It was working on Windows but when I switch into Linux it stops working.

Here is the caller and the array variable :

```
char *hashes[numberOfchar];
PutInArray(textName, numberOfchar, &hashes);
```

And here is the function (the `void*` is for the next part of the program, threading) :

```
void* PutInArray(char* k, int d, char *tab[d]) {
  FILE* fp = NULL;
  int i;
  fp = fopen(k, "r");

  if(fp != NULL) {
    for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
      tab[i] = (char *)malloc((34) * sizeof(char));
      fgets(tab[i], 34, fp);

    }
    fclose(fp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Pass 'd' as a separate parameter.

Comment: i tried doing it ther is no errors but the program stops when i execute it like this `PutInArray(textName,numberOfchar,&hashes[numberOfchar]);`

Comment: Formatting/indentation..........................

Comment: i didnt understood you ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ If you quote error messages, do not delete the interesting parts.

Comment: @HiiroProcrastination, It seems you need to learn a basics. You do some weird things in the prototype and in the caller. Try to understand what you are doing there.

Comment: how can I make it better? my intention is to read data from a file and put it in an array of strings when I do it with no functions, it works but once I put it in functions it confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see how function calls work for other types.

You have a variable `int v;` and a function `void foo(int x)` (the variable declaration and the parameter declaration look the same). You call `foo(v)`. You also have a function `void bar(int* x)` (the variable declaration has one star less than the parameter declaration). You call `bar(&v)`.

You have a variable `int* v;` and a function `void foo(int* x)` (the variable declaration and the parameter declaration look the same). You call `foo(v)`. You also have a function `void bar(int** x)` (the variable declaration has one star less than the parameter declaration). You call `bar(&v)`.

You have a variable `const struct moo ***v` and a function `void foo(const struct moo ***x)` (the variable declaration and the parameter declaration look the same). You call `foo(v)`. You also have a function `void bar(const struct moo ****x)` (the variable declaration has one star less than the parameter declaration). You call `bar(&v)`.

You have a variable `char *hashes[numberOfchar]` and a function `void* PutInArray(char* k, int d, char *tab[d])`. The variable declaration and the parameter declaration still look the same. Why on God's green earth stick `&` in front of the variable?

I hear you saying "but I want to pass `hashes` by reference, and to pass by reference I need to use `&`". Nope, arrays are automatically passed by reference (or rather an array automatically gets converted to a pointer of its first element; parameters of array type are similarly adjusted so that the rule formulated above just works).

For completeness, the analogue of `bar` would have a parameter that looks like this:

```
char* (*tab)[numberOfchar]
```

and if you had such parameter, you would have to use `&hashes`. But you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost OK. Concerning the error/warning you get, just write `PutInArray(textName, numberOfchar, hashes)` instead of `PutInArray(textName, numberOfchar, &hashes)` for the following reason:

In function `PutInArray(char* k, int d, char *tab[d])`, `char *tab[d]` has the same meaning as `char*[]` and `char**`, i.e. it behaves as a pointer to a pointer to a char.

Then you define `hashes` as `char *hashes[numberOfchar]`, which is an array of pointers to char. When using `hashes` as function argument, `hashes` decays to a pointer to the first entry of the array, i.e. to a value of type `char **`, which matches the type of argument `tab`. However, if you pass `&hashes`, then you'd pass a pointer to type `char *[]`, which is one indirection to much. (BTW: passing `&hashes[0]` would be OK).

BTW: `PutInChar` should either return a value or should be declared as `void PutInArray(char* k, int d, char *tab[d])` (not `void*`).

Comment: your solution is the right one but i have 2 question why should it return a value when i'm changing the value of hashes globaly ?, i tested your solution on both ubuntu and windows the windows is working perfectly but ubunto is taking only taking the pair index of the array ?

Comment: concerning question 1, see edited answer. Concerning 2, can you post what   ubuntu is complaining about? I do not understand the "pair index of the array"-thing.

Comment: here is what ubuntu is giving me when i try to print the value of the array         `hashes in 0 is : 6e7aeb36036e8ad8550e1acf0ff35eed`                                  `hashes in 1 is : `                                                                                              the value is in hex wich is okey

Comment: then you could just write `return NULL`; I get even a compiler error otherwise.